# Do moderators want to be notified when Stack Overflow questions get migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

Following up to [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl):

Since the main opposition position, which based on votes is pretty popular, is essentially "you're not getting rid of the crap, so we're going to keep flushing," it doesn't look like we're going to stop getting terribad Stack Overflow questions for some time.

There was a feature suggestion that moderators should be able to "accept" incoming migrations to police what's sent to their Stack Exchange site: failing that feature being implemented, do moderators want all potentially terrible migrated questions to be flagged so they can make a call about closing them without waiting for 5 close votes that may or may not come? I've been flagging the obvious career advice and duplicate questions, but there are some potentially bad questions beyond that.

Comment: The toilets of ones are the palaces of the others ;)

Comment: We have recently imported questions available, actually 10k+ users have. Anyway it's a good feature to improve our job. Some career advice has been reopened.

Comment: Thanks for taking yet another opportunity to misconstrue my answer. "Lead by example" is hardly equivalent to "give up". And moderators already have a list of incoming (migrated) questions in the 10k tools, if you absolutely must treat them differently from the "native-born" questions.

Comment: @MrCRT to use the parlance of our times, "lead by example." Nowhere did I say anyone said "give up." But thank you and @bigown for pointing out the newly migrated questions section, which is what I wanted to know. One of you should make that an answer so it could be accepted.

Comment: @Mark: heh, touche! My feeling is that you'll always need to be vigilant about examining/editing/closing/voting/flagging questions regardless of source - the "active" list is your friend, moderator or user. You may be fixated on migrated questions now, but as the site grows it'll be home-grown questions that make up the majority of those needing attention (if they don't already) - if you take a bad question as an opportunity to address similar questions already on the site, then the site will actually *improve* with each new post...

Comment: This should probably be a topic all its own, but why are migrated questions "pushed" from SO? Shouldn't it be a "pull request" instead, so that the destination moderators have the final say over whether the migration even happens at all?

Comment: @Eric - that's a problem with all migrations. Super User is constantly getting questions from SO that don't fit any more. There's a link to the target site's FAQ on the migrate dialog but I suspect that hardly anyone clicks it when deciding where to migrate.

Comment: @ChrisF - Thanks. I was pretty sure that's the case, but it still makes more sense to me to have the destination site in charge of deciding the appropriateness of the migration and finalizing it. That way, they don't feel like they're getting dumped on. Nothing should get pushed to PSE without the PSE moderators' permission. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a link on the 10K tools pages - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools/recently-imported - (it's on [this tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=links&daterange=last2days)) that shows all the questions recently imported (the name's a give-away really ;) ). Something to look forward to when you get to 10K.

We (moderators and 10K users) just have to remember to click it from time to time.

Please feel free to flag anything you come across that you think doesn't belong - though don't forget to vote as well. It looks better if there are more names on a closed question.

Answer (score 2):

The original charter for PSE was much broader. Originally "Not Programming Related", we were seeking a place to ask and entertain questions that would have been closed as "not programming related" on SO.

Mostly, NPR was used when a question was more about *programmers* than *programming*. Now we've introduced six guidelines for better subjective questions, which are in their own right open to subjective interpretation. I might feel that a question satisfies "*Great subjective questions are more than just mindless social fun*", where someone else might not.

Looking at the first page of users, I think we're only a few weeks away from having a sufficient number of 10k users that have access to tools that show them where problematic questions might be.

Is it *really* enough of an issue to be concerned with at this point?

Comment: The 10K tools you are talking about are very light. There is not much moderation tools. I think the solution is having more moderators. They can't do all that job alone, it's too difficult. Two or three more would be great. I think Mark, Anna and you would be perfect. You are very different.

Comment: All that's great, but has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Question migrations, both in and out, should be a dedicated tab on the 10k tools page -- Marc will implement this as soon as is reasonably possible.

Comment: Awesome news...