# What's up with all of the migrated questions being closed the same day they are migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, frustration

I keep finding interesting sounding questions that are closed only to find out they were closed the same day they were migrated because they shouldn't be here.

Sounds like we need more coordination between the people migrating questions and the people closing them!

Here's a sample question that was closed within minutes of being migrated:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37804/which-big-web-applications-use-linq-to-sql

Thanks to whoever can shed some light on this for me.  Also, if I missed a Meta question that already addresses this, please point me in the right direction.  I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you linked to one of the questions I closed, I'll add my 2 cents.  Yes there needs to be more communication between people on SO closing/migrating questions and mods/users on Programmers.

I can understand how it happens.  A question is posted on SO that clearly doesn't belong there, someone votes to migrate it to Programmers thinking it's not about code so it should live here, not really know if it meets Programmers guidelines.  It actually happens a lot.

I do know that in recent weeks that some of the mods on SO have started [asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1162) here on Meta whether a question should be migrated to Programmers or just closed on SO.  This goes a long way to help the situation.

What it doesn't fix is the situation where 5 SO users vote to migrate a question here.  They may or may not know whether it's a good question to migrate and they may or may not care (as long as it's gone from SO).  I don't know how that gets fixed.

Here's some other discussions about the same topic:

[Do moderators want to be notified when Stack Overflow questions get migrated?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872)

[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382)

Comment: 5 Programmers users (or at least 3) should have to vote to accept the question too.

Comment: @Jon Hopkins Where would those users see the questions they can vote for?

Comment: There was some talk a while back about allowing mods to review questions that were being migrated but that didn't really go anywhere.  It could also end up being a lot of extra work for mods to do (although it could be opened up to 10K+ users as well).

Comment: @Jon - if you have an idea of how that might work I would suggest you make that a feature request here or on meta.SO.  Perhaps it could go somewhere.

Comment: @Jon Hopkins - Is there a way to give the users on SO that are voting to migrate questions feedback that the question(s) they migrated didn't fit the site they migrated them to?

Comment: @Jeff - When you vote to close you give the reason off-topic which I guess would allow you to check this (if you cross referenced it with migrated questions).

Comment: @bizclop - It would potentially have to sit under the tools section along with flags and so on.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of questions get migrated to Programmers by people who are not very well familiar with the site's [FAQ and guidelines](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq). Such questions often get closed because they would get closed if they were asked here directly instead of having been migrated in from another site.

The specific question you used as an example is not a constructive subjective question. It's just asking for a list of sites. The answers are objective (either a site uses LINQ to SQL or not), short (what else is there to say besides leaving the URL?), and ultimately don't fit well within a Q&A voting model on StackExchange.